# using subquery to return aggregate function(sum) with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, subquery, grouping

I am looking to produce a sum (or count) for every row in a table based on multiple criteria from the specific row.

I can get this to work using a subquery but only with one criteria. If I add a 2nd then I am required to use grouping which then returns multiple rows and breaks the query.

```
SELECT top (10)
       [DateTime]
      ,[CustNo]
      ,[AccountId2]
      ,[amount]
     into ##allMM
  FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
  where CustNo in ('123456')

select 
       [DateTime]
      ,[CustNo]
      ,[AccountId2]
      ,[ClientIp]
      ,[ReferenceNo]
      ,[ErrorCode]
      ,[ErrorMessage]
      (select 
       sum(amount) 
       from ##allMM 
       group by ##allMM.CustNo 
       having ##allMM.CustNo = a.CustNo and ##allMM.DateTime < a.DateTime
      ) as sumCustno
into ##finalSel
FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs] a
where CustNo in ('123456')

select * from finalSel
drop table ##allMM, ##finalSel
```

The above uses two having criteria (custno and DateTime) but I will likely need to tack on additional criteria later. I expect the output to be a single sum of all amounts in the first table that meet all conditions of the sub query. I am currently constraining to single account as the database is huge.

Final result should look something like

```
datetime  | custno | .... | sumCustNo
 3Jul2019 | 123456 | .....| 681.25
 2Jul2019 | 123456 | .... | 251.76
30Jun2019 | 345678 | .... | 1237.93
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Right now you only show the result. Is like you give us a cake and ask us replicated without tell us what are the ingridients

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a simple `group by`?  I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]), CustNo,
       SUM([amount]),
       SUM(SUM(amount)) OVER (PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]))
FROM [OLBRET_COPY].[dbo].[ActivityLogs]
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]), CustNo;
```